# What is the difference between Update() and FixedUpdate() and how should the differences be applied into controlling movement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code to handle he simple player movement for a game object. It allows the user to move the object up and down, left and right, and enables rotation.

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 10f;
    public float rotateSpeed = 10f;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    Vector2 movement;

    void Update()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotateSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

I am under the impression that:

- `Update()` is called every gametick and
- it is better suited for general detection, such as keypresses.

and that:

- `FixedUpdate()` is called 50 times per second and
- it is better for game object transformation.

So if my key input detection is in the `Update()` method

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
{
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotateSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

Then should my rotation code be in `FixedUpdate()`. If so, how do I get it to run there while still detecting the keypress in `Update()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FixedUpdate** is used to be in-time with the physics system.  You would use **FixedUpdate** when applying a force (or in your case, **MovePosition**) to a *RigidBody*.

As for your **Rotate**, you should do it in **Update**.  That will give you the most accurate position for the next rendered frame (even if **Update** is called multiple times before the next frame).  Also, you should use *Time.deltaTime* in your **Update** calculation.  Like so:

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

*Time.fixedDeltaTime* is for **FixedUpdate**.

Ref: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html